# Cloudflare SSL faile to upload

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

I have generated certificate on digicert.com and downloaded the certificate. When i am uploading csr and private key to cloudflare SSL configuration. It showing wierd issue:

> 'Unable to find a host name belonging to the zone on the certificate'

Answer (score 0):

The error message really say what is the problem, the all CN or alt names domains in the certificate do no match the current domain you are trying to install the certificate.

In another words, your cloudflare domain is not in the certificate you are trying to install. Recheck your certificate. [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) and [keystore-explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) (kse) are good tools to check and manage certificate